# how to replace a word from a paragraph ,in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a paragraph

```
"hi boss how is your health. <p><div> my office is big Perl </div></p>"
```

I want to remove the `<div></div>` tags alone , so that the updated string will look like

```
"hi boss how is your health. <p>my office is big Perl</p>".
```

What should i do?

Comment: What do you want, explain properly

Comment: Those two strings are the same but one has a space if you want to remove the space use `rtrim()`

Comment: Do you mean this?: [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: @JammyDodger231 not the same, he want to remove _html_ tags

Comment: @FaresM. I commented before he had edited the post to add the tags

Comment: Read from here http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: @JammyDodger231 can you give answer for my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP Way**, use `str_replace` as following :

```
<?PHP
$string = "hi boss how is your health. <p><div>my office is big Perl</div></p>";

$string=str_replace('<div>', '', $string);
$string=str_replace('</div>', '', $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

**Easy Way**, visit any online text manipulation tools website and edit your whole text paragraph once without needs any PHP knowledge  ex: [Text Manipulation Tools](http://texttools.ml/view-Free-Online-Text-Tools)

Comment: but its not printing link // Prints "hi boss how is your health. <p>my office is big Perl</p>".it echo like this // Prints "hi boss how is your health. my office is big Perl"

Comment: I've edited the code, please note that it prints `hi boss how is your health. <p>my office is big Perl</p>` if you just made view source as it HTML code, see the image http://i.cubeupload.com/5eFjhy.png

Comment: This answer is copied from my answer after 20 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Just use strip_tags function in php to remove . Use the code below

```
<?php
$string = "hi boss how is your health. <div> my office is big Perl </div>";
echo strip_tags($string,"<p>");  // Prints "hi boss how is your health. my office is big Perl"
?>
```

You can allow some or more tags if you want. Please read the full reference here
http://php.net/strip_tags

Hope this helps you

Comment: if $string = "hi boss how is your health. <p><div> my office is big Perl </div></p>";i should replace only <div></div>
  results "hi boss how is your health. <p>my office is big Perl</p>"

Comment: Edited my answer have a look at it again

Comment: This is the better solution than to use `str_replace` for closing and opening tags this should be best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip_tags($string);` function of PHP.

For more ref : http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 1):

If u want to remove only div tags then use str_replace like below-

```
$string = "hi boss how is your health. <p><div>my office is big Perl</div></p>";
$string = str_replace('<div>' , '' , $string);
$string = str_replace('</div>' , '' , $string);
```

and if u want to remove all html tags, then use strip_tags as per other members given suggestion.

Comment: because i missed p tag in my string first time..i m correcting my code

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the strip tags function built into PHP: http://php.net/strip_tags it strips html tags from the input string e.g.

```
$text = "hi boss how is your health. <div> my office is big Perl </div>";
echo strip_tags($text);
//Will echo "hi boss how is your health. my office is big Perl"
```

Comment: :no ,if my text contains$text = "hi boss how is your health. <p><div> my office is big Perl </div></p>";i want to remove <div></div> alone

Comment: If what text contains the text variable?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in php that takes three text parameters.

- The first parameter is the text that will be processed.
- The second parameter is the string to be replaced.
- The third parameter is the string that will be placed in the new string.

The function searches for the second text parameter in the first text parameter
and replaces it with the text the third parameter if found. After the replacement the function returns the new text to be printed on the screen.

Comment: with out using replace